# Creating a people-centric search with elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I currently have a content-centric elastic search (in AWS) index containing articles with the following data:

```
{article id, title, keywords, summary text, [name 1 [completion rate], name 2 [completion rate]...], creation date}
```

Each person associated with each article has an associated completion rate.

When I search for a keyword names are returned from the top-matching documents. I would like to pivot this to a person-centric model where:

```
name 1, completion rate {
   { [article id, title, keywords, summary text , creation date],
     [article id, title, keywords, summary text , creation date],
     ...}

name 2, completion rate {
   { [article id, title, keywords, summary text , creation date],
     [article id, title, keywords, summary text , creation date],
     ...}
```

When I do a search I would like to:

_ Match & rank people based on all articles linked to them (search terms should match title, keywords and summary text fields within a person entity)

_ Tune ranking of a person based on their completion rate (people with higher completion rates should rank higher)

_ Tune ranking of a person based on creation date (I want recent articles to contribute more to the overall ranking of a person entity than older articles)

Is this a possible set up? Any ideas on how to do this greatly appreciated!

Max.

Comment: Are you hoping to accomplish this within the existing index structure?  Or are you planning to build a second "person-centric" index?

Comment: Thanks Peter - either way is good as long as it gets to the outcome and doesn't add too much overhead during the search.